# Existe lista de de objetos no envio de requests no html?

Tags: html, python, aplicação-web, flask

Estou desenvolvendo um pequeno projeto web em python(flask) para aprendizado próprio e me deparei com algo que nunca havia encarado antes.

Tenho um formulário de cadastro onde os campos de uma informação são dinâmicos, ou seja, via jquery eu posso criar e excluir campos pois não sei quantos links o usuário enviará. Minha dúvida é a seguinte, como eu recebo o request desse form no meu código python se não sei quantos campos serão enviados? Existe alguma espécie de lista no request onde eu possa criar 'objetos' para enviar tudo junto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como diz documentação [aqui](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request.form), o `request.form` é um `ImmutableMultiDict` que se comporta como um dicionário.

Você pode usar métodos de dicionário nele normalmente, como `request.form.keys()`, `request.form.items()` ou até mesmo iterar diretamente nele para ver todos os nomes usados:

```
for chave in request.form:
    print(chave, request.form[chave])
```

Vai imprimir no console tudo que chegou do formulário.

Se a sua página enviar multiplos campos com o mesmo nome, mesmo assim você pode pegar usando `getlist`:

```
request.form.getlist(chave)
```

Vai retornar uma lista com todos os valores com aquele nome.

Comment: Achoque vale esclarecer em outras palavras - todos os campos de formulário que do lado do HTML tiverem o atributo "name" igual são agrupados no request.form do flask, o conteúdo de cada campo como um item de uma lista.